# C# code to get maximum dpi of installed or selected printer

Tags: c#, printing, dpi

I want to get Maximum Dpi of installed or selected printer. I tried

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        MessageBox.Show(ps.PrinterResolutions.ToString());
```

and I get this output: System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings+PreinterResolutionCollection
(The desired output is 600x600).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
var maxResolution = ps.PrinterResolutions.OfType<PrinterResolution>()
                                         .OrderByDescending(r => r.X)
                                         .ThenByDescending(r => r.Y)
                                         .First();
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}x{1}", maxResolution.X, maxResolution.Y));
```

Comment: shows me an error Error 4 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.PrinterResolutionCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.PrinterResolutionCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @Dhaval ensure that you have directive `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @Dhaval also I edited my answer to work with non-generic `IEnumerable` that `PrinterResolutions` implements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PrinterResolutions is a collection and your trying to convert it to a string value.

Comment: so how to get the desired output that is 600x600 (my pritner's maximum dpi as in specification.)

Answer (score 0):

Printer resolutions is a collection, you will need to iterate through it to read all of the available resolutions, something like:

```
foreach (string installedPrinter in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    var ps = new PrinterSettings { PrinterName = installedPrinter };
    var maxResolution = ps.PrinterResolutions.Cast<PrinterResolution>().OrderByDescending(pr => pr.X).First();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}x{2}", installedPrinter, maxResolution.X, maxResolution.Y);
}
```

Or to display all printers and all of their PrinterResolutions

```
foreach (string installedPrinter in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    var ps = new PrinterSettings { PrinterName = installedPrinter };
    foreach (PrinterResolution printerResolution in ps.PrinterResolutions)
    {
        var tpl = printerResolution.Kind == PrinterResolutionKind.Custom ? "{0}: {1} ({2}x{3})" : "{0}: {1}";
        Console.WriteLine(tpl, installedPrinter, printerResolution.Kind, printerResolution.X, printerResolution.Y);
    }       
}
```

Comment: to Dve: i tried that but that shows output like [PrinterResolution High], [PrinterResolution Medium], [PrinterResolution Low], [PrinterResolution Draft]. But i want the answer 600x600 (i.e. my printer's maximum dpi as in specification.)

Comment: i got three answers. third is Canon iP1300 -1x-1. what is -1x-1. can you explain?

Comment: @Dhaval The resolution is only returned if the PrinterResolutionKind == custom. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printerresolutions(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I use (.NET 2.0, so without Linq)

```
public static int CompareResolutions(System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution y, System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution x)
{
    if (x.X*x.Y > y.X*y.Y) 
        return 1;
    else if (x.X * x.Y < y.X * y.Y) 
        return -1;

    return 0;
}


public static System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution GetMaxResolution(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pd)
{
    return GetMaxResolution(pd.PrinterSettings);
}

public static System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution GetMaxResolution(System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings ps)
{
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution prMax = null;

    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution> ls = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ps.PrinterResolutions.Count; ++i)
    {
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution pres = ps.PrinterResolutions[i];
        ls.Add(pres);
    } // Next i

    ls.Sort(CompareResolutions);

    if (ls.Count > 0)
        prMax = ls[0];

    ls.Clear();
    ls = null;

    return prMax;
}
```