# Enforce program settings

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have made a small c# winforms program which among other stuff, prints barcodes. On some client machines where it operates, some other software for printing barcodes overrides my settings for printing the barcode and it resizes just the barcode.

If I change the code just for that machine, it either repositions the image (makes it smaller as well), or stretches it so wide that it cuts off one third of it. Currently I am only using the printing settings to set the margins to 0 and set the paper mode to landscape in the print dialog, and the image size is fixed in the printing process(I used constants). Below is the code for when the user clicks the print button, and also two constants defined outside of it.

```
    const int barcodeX = 570;
    const int barcodeY = 135;

    private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DocPrint.DocumentName = "Document";
        elements = 0;
        PrintDialog.Document = DocumentDrucker;     

        DocPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        DocPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
        DocPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
        DocPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
        DocPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;

        //DocumentDrucker.OriginAtMargins = false;

        if (PrintDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            DocPrint.Print();
    }
```

Also the lines to encode and print the barcode in the printing process. The barcodePoint is where the barcode is positioned, on the paper.

```
b.Encode(TYPE.CODE128A, "SBD" + currentItem.Text.Substring(0, 3) + currentItem.Text.Substring(4), Color.Black, Color.Transparent, barcodeX, barcodeY);
graphic.DrawImage(b.EncodedImage, barcodePoint);
```

The program runs fine under any other circumstances, so I have identified the problem, I just do not know how to go around the other software's settings. I have already reinstalled the drivers for the printer (no success), as well logged in as a different user on the same computer, and that made my program work. So it has something to do with the software installed on it, I just don't know what.
At first I thought it was a problem with the drivers and the OS, but I tried it on other computers and it worked fine as well. The problem persists just on the computers with the software.

Is there any way to make my program force it's printing settings for the barcode image, since the software installed on the machines always uses it's own settings? Or to make sure that the settings in my code will not be changed?

Uninstalling the software is not an option, as it is used for other processes.

EDIT: I have run the program from both my user logon (no software) and the target machine user (both on the same machine). The settings were identical in both cases, the only thing different was that on the target machine, the software was installed. What are some ways to make sure that my settings are enforced, instead of an X program overwriting them?

Comment: Is the printer resolution showing up on this computer completely different? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13720652/3090544

Comment: No, I have used my program on the same computer, just on a different user(no software installed), and it worked fine.

Comment: Check all the parameters of the `PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();` when running under your user and running under the problematic user

Comment: Okay, I will try that and edit the question accordingly. 
Anything else I should or can do before I test it again? Is there no way to programmatically enforce the settings of my program?

Comment: I have identified the problem software, but I do not know how to fix it. Basically, the target machine has some P-Touch label printer installed, and the software always resizes my barcodes to fit on the label. 

The software can not be uninstalled, as it is used for other processes. What can I do to make sure that it does not interfere with my program/that my program overrides the P-Touch software settings or the template?